# Discord.py error handling not outputting a message?

Tags: discord.py

I have tried making an error message when a user does not have the permissions to use the command, this is because I kept getting an error in the console the code is supposed to send a message in chat when the user doesn't have permissions to use it, the error has disappeared from the console but it does not output a message

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, limit: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = limit)
    await ctx.send('Cleared by {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))

@clear.error
async def clear_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('Sorry, you do not have permissions to do that!')
```

Comment: If it doesn't output a message, it means that the error is not `MissingPermissions`. Could you try adding `print(error)` in the error handler and telling us what happens?

Comment: Also I have exactly the same code for my bot, but instead of checking for `MissingPermissions` I check for `CheckFailure`, which works fine for me.

Comment: I have tried putting ```print(error)``` into my code and ran it but the console still comes out as blank @kr8gz.
I have also tried using ```CheckFailure``` in the code and still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using an error handling function, you have to do `async def clear_error(ctx, error):`. Basically you just have to swap the parameters' places.

```py
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('Sorry, you do not have permissions to do that!')
```

Comment: That worked, I would have never have found that thanks!